# SSRS URL Java Field Value link

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I am trying to pass a Field!GoogleLink.Value as URL as on open url action in an SSRS report. The Field!GoogleLink.Value returns a value :

> https://www.google.co.uk/maps/dir/WA128AF/WA11GG

The idea is the link opens up google maps and show you directions. The URL part works but I cant wrap in the Java to open in a new window.

I've tried dozens of variations :
`=Code.OpenURL("https://www.google.co.uk/maps/dir/" &Parameters!Postcode.Value &"/"& Fields!Postcode.Value )`  - tried to do this like i would a report server link

Tried some custom code :

```
Function OpenURL(ByVal URL As String) As String
Return “javascript:void(window.open(‘” & URL & “‘,’_blank’))”
End Function
```

`=Code.OpenURL(Fields!GoogleMaps.Value)`

This is essentially the query im looking for

```
javascript:void(window.open('" & Fields!GoogleMaps.Value & "','_blank'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Click on a textbox, right mouse click, select Text box properties,select action, select go to URL, in the fx expression enter the following:

="javascript:void(window.open('https://www.google.co.uk/maps/dir/WA128AF/WA11GG', '_blank'))"

Save and deploy your report to your reportserver, when you click on the text box, the URL is opened in a new page.